# Aggregate mean in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, mean

I am trying to view the **mean values of height, grouped by eye color**
of the characters, that have a number in their name.
I tried it with aggregate but I can't figure out the solution

```
sw %>%
  filter(grepl('[0-9]',name))%>%
     aggregate(height~eye_color,mean)%>%
        setNames(c("Eye color","Mean"))
```

Comment: Pipe and filter() mean you are using dplyr. Why dont you use group_by() and summarise()?

Comment: yes i tried that too, but still don't know how to do it

Comment: if you want full answer please provide reproducible example. But in the nutshell group_by(Eyecolor) %>%  summarize( new_name = mean(height)) 
note that Eyecolor must have no space

Comment: Allright i got It. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

starwars %>%
  filter(grepl('[0-9]',name)) %>% 
  group_by(eye_color) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(height))
```

Output:

```
  eye_color  mean
* <chr>     <dbl>
1 black        NA
2 red         131
3 red, blue    96
4 yellow      167
```

Answer (score 3):

If we want to use `base R` (`R 4.1.0`)

```
sw |>
    subset(grepl('[0-9]', name)) |>
    {\(dat) aggregate(cbind(Mean = height) ~ eye_color, data = dat, mean)}()
```

-output

```
#  eye_color Mean
#1       red  131
#2 red, blue   96
#3    yellow  167
```

#### data

```
data(starwars)
sw <- starwars
```

Comment: First answer (that I've seen) using R-4.1's `|>` and anon-func `\(dat) ..`, nice.

Comment: if in doubt, `starwars` is in the `dplyr` package